# Como mudar o tema de um App para Android para parecer com o iOS?

Tags: android, ios, temas

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo **Android** e gostaria de utilizar um **tema** que o deixe parecido com aplicativos do **iPhone (iOS)**.
Há algum lugar onde eu possa obter esse tema ou forma simples de implementar isso?

Comment: Depende, qual iOS ? a nova versão flat?

Comment: Talvez não ache um tema todo pronto parecido com iOS, se procurar componentes(Buttons, List, etc) com tema do iOS e desenhar seu `theme` com esses componentes terá um bom resultado.

Comment: iOS 6, preferencialmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apesar de não ser exatamente apenas um tema e não permitir interface iOS em Android, e sim um framework completo para desenvolvimento mobile, o Framework7 parece uma solução interessante para simular interfaces nativas dos dispositivos.

Para saber mais: https://framework7.io/

Answer (score 6):

Apesar de ser possível fazer isso com temas e customizando componentes, isso não é recomendável pelo simples fato do aplicativo ter um comportamento de app de iOS podendo comprometer a usabilidade do app como um todo, pois os usuários não estão habituados com a plataforma.

Esse texto explica melhor porque isso não é recomendado:
https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: Apesar de ser a mais pura verdade, isso não responde a pergunta (se é que essa pergunta merece uma resposta).

Comment: Sei que não é ideal, mas como comentado acima, é apenas para adicionar alguns aspectos visuais interessantes.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo eu não faria isso! Minha sugestão é que respeite as regras de UX e utilize "a cara de seu aplicativo" conforme a plataforma que ele pertence.

Até Breve!